# Would a question which will probably turn into a discussion should be asked on SF?

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to ask a question which will probably turn into a discussion soon enough because there's no one absolute answer and there are a few ways to achieve the aim of the question I'm going to ask.

I'm sure that the question will contribute to SF as it's related to a very "hot" subject.

So I wonder, would such a question be compatible with SF's rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question here is too abstract, it's difficult to answer without knowing the question you want to ask on ServerFault.

Given the paucity of detail, all we can really say is just ask your question. The worst that will happen is it gets closed and you may loose a few Useless Inernet Points.

Comment: OMG!  Not my Internet points!